# Elastic search to index full relational database - Is it a good idea?

Tags: sql-server, database, spring, jpa, elasticsearch

For implementing relational database search, I am thinking if Pushing all data from  relation DB to Elastic is a good idea. I know putting relation DB data into elastic search would mean that everything will be indexed and I can search for a string against all of my database tables but copying everything from DB to elastic is like duplicating the data storage.

Thoughts? Is it a good idea to use Elastic search as a full text indexer of relational DB for searching purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury of infrastructure you can go ahead with it.

Minimum Infra requirement:

You need at test 3 nodes to form a stable cluster.
Per Node:
RAM: 32 GB (Max RAM recommended)
Storage: 1 - 2 TB (depending on your data)
For more info please refer ([infra](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/deploy.html))

While logstash (another app from elasticsearch community) will help you migrate the data seamlessly with minimal effort. Just use the JDBC plugin. [jdbc plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html)